# How to get Haskell Documentation to appear in IntelliJ?

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

Haskell has documentation for "putStrLn" here...

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=putStrLn

But when I use the IntelliJ IDE (default Haskell plugin), I don't get documentation. Auto-complete works for "putStrLn", and it says "String -> IO()" in the auto-complete menu, but when I press Ctr-Q or Ctr-Space, it says "No documentation found."

How do I get pop-up documentation for Haskell in IntelliJ?

Trying alternative "HaskForce" plugin. Cannot figure out how to do basic "hello world".

*** Update on Haskforce ***

-- Start with getting the basic Haskell stuff:

https://eschulte.github.io/emacs24-starter-kit/starter-kit-haskell.html

-- Then get Haskforce (and uninstall Haskell Plugin for IntelliJ)

[image: Haskforce Plugin]

-- Then set up the tools in "Settings"

[image: Haskforce Tools]

-- Set compiler settings

[image: Haskforce compiler settings]

^ I turned on "Install Cabal Dependencies" because when it was off I got this nasty message on Run:

```
Information:cabal: Install dependencies
Information:cabal: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
Information:cabal: next goal: base (dependency of HaskforceProject-0.1.0.0)
Information:cabal: base>=4.7 && <5)
Information:cabal: 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2,
Information:cabal: requires installed instance)
Information:cabal: null
Information:2/8/16 1:23 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 650ms
Error:cabal: install dependencies failed.
```

Set run configuration ("Run > Edit Configuration" must be done before clicking Run arrow):

[image: Run Configuration]

When I click the arrow to run, I get this message:

[image: Not Working]

```
ghc-modi error
Unable to parse problems from ghc-modi: cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing: base >=4.7 && 5 ghc-mod: readProcess: cabal "configure" "--with-ghc=ghc" "--flags" "" (exit 1): failed
```

Note that these screenshots are from a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with an install of Haskell essentials and Leskah from the Ubuntu apt-get package manager.

Got Haskforce working by changing "base >=4.7 && 5" to "base >=4.6 && 5" in .cabal file, but still no pop-up documentation.

*** Update ***

Still no pop up documentation, but I got HoogleIt plugin for IntelliJ and a Hoogle plugin for Atom that searches for functions in Hoogle (Haskell Google).

Comment: I only have very limited knowledge of Java, but by the [source](https://github.com/atsky/haskell-idea-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/org/jetbrains/haskell/doc/HaskellQuickDocumentationProvider.kt) I guess it's not implemented.

Comment: Hi, I'm the primary author of HaskForce.  It sounds like we have two questions here, how to get documentation, and then how to do a basic "hello world".  The documentation lookup is very simple in HaskForce, and there are some outstanding issues to enhance it.  As for "hello world", if you are facing an issue please submit a ticket on the GitHub issue tracker with details about the problems you are experiencing - https://github.com/carymrobbins/intellij-haskforce/issues

Comment: @pyrospade - I added the full description with screenshots to "Update on Haskforce".

Comment: @MichaelLafayette - It looks like you have `base >=4.7 && <5` as a dependency in your `.cabal` file, but your compiler only has up to `4.6` according to the error message.  You should probably update the `.cabal` file to use `base >=4.6 && <5` as the dependency.  It seems like you may have started this out as a stack project, then switched to cabal without updating your dependencies.

Comment: @pyrospade - All I did was "File > New > Project > Haskell > Build with Cabal > Next" and it automatically creates a Project.cabal file with "build-depends: base >= 4.7 && < 5". Also, even though it runs with "base >= 4.6 && < 5", the auto-complete does not work at all, not even for "putStrLn". I type -- "putStr" *Ctr-Space* -- and I get "HaskForce: no completion found." Also, debug mode (Shift + F9) doesn't even print "Hello World".

Comment: @MichaelLafayette - This would probably be easier to work through if you open an issue on the github issue tracker (I don't get reasonable notifications from stack exchange).  You could also ping me on #haskforce on freenode IRC (I'm crobbins) so we could have the conversation real-time.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the Hoogle plugin. IntelliJ has a HoogleIt plugin (Ctr-Shift-H) that searches for Haskell functions in Hoogle. Atom text editor has a similar plugin.

Javadoc style documentation is not available for Haskell in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I'm answering my own question again. I think if you install the newest EclipseFP and configure it correctly, you can get auto-complete with documentation.

See picture:

[image: Documentation]

^ Note that EclipseFP is not download-and-run like Java Hello World. It apparently needs some configuring.

First install:

http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html

Then do "Extra configuration steps"